# Can a PSN cars be split among shared accounts?

Tags: ps4

I have a PS4, and I share it with 2 other people for a total of 3 accounts.

I bought a PlayStation Plus 30 day membership for $30, and I have 3 small cards valued at $10 each.

Can I use each card on each of the 3 accounts?

Comment: Anyone????..lll

Comment: Patience.  You will get an answer soon enough.

Comment: Please try to change your title to something that another user can search for, if they have this issue, in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you purchased a 30 day membership PSN card.

It seems like you purchased [this](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/sony-10-playstation-network-cards-3-pack-multi/8438015.p?id=1219334538829&skuId=8438015), which is a 3-pack of $10 cards for the PSN store.

If this is the case, then you won't be able to activate a PSN subscription with these, but can, instead, only use them to purchase things from the Playstation Store, from within a PS3, Vita, PS4 or on [store.playstation.com](http://store.playstation.com).

If what you purchased is, in fact, a 30-day membership (which I highly doubt, unfortunately, since you have 3 cards), or some strange kind of high-cost 3-pack of 30-day memberships ([You can buy a 3-month sub for $24.99](http://www.gamestop.com/console-subscriptions/playstation-plus-3-month-membership/84612)).

You have two options.

1. Yes, you could use one card for each person, and every person could get 30 days of PSN membership.

***OR***

2. You can use all 90 days, that you have purchased, on the PSN account that is the primary, for this PS4.

Personally, I prefer option 2, because the main account gets all of the benefits of PSN and the other accounts get many of the important features.  One one user can be logged in, at once, so having three accounts each paying for PSN is a massive waste unless the other accounts REALLY need the features of PSN that non-primaries don't get.

You can find a list of all of the limitations on [Playstation's site, here](https://www.playstation.com/en-au/get-help/help-library/playstation-plus/information---benefits/sharing-playstation-plus-benefits-with-a-friend-on-playstation-4/)

The only things that your friends could not use, of the PSN subscription, as guest accounts, would be:

```
- Purchasing PlayStation Plus discounted products from PlayStation Store  
- Online game save storage  
- Auto patch download  
- PlayStation Plus exclusive early access to game trials
```